# Special groups, special resolutions and group cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$ Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. And let $\Z$ be the ring of integers.
Under which condition on the group $G$ can we find a free resolution $F_{\bullet}\rightarrow \Z$
of $\Z$ as left $\Z[G]$-module satisfying the conditions ?

1. $F_{\bullet}\rightarrow \Z$ is a finite resolution I.e. each $F_{i}$ is finitely generated free left $\Z[G]$-module. And $F_{i}=0$ for $i$ enough big.
2. $F_{\bullet}\rightarrow \Z$ is also a resolution of $\Z[G]$-bimodules. I.e. for each $i$, $F_{i+1}\rightarrow F_{i}$ and $F_{0}\rightarrow \Z$ are maps of $\Z[G]$-bimodule.

In this question each free $\Z[G]$-module is seen as $\Z[G]$-bimodule in the obvious way.

As far as I know, there is a big class of groups satisfying condition 1. I will be happy if one can provide a non-abelian example satisfying 1 and 2. Or a proof that such non-abelian group does not exist.

Comment: No. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ of Laurent polynomials, and $\mathbb{Z}$ admits the resolution


$0\rightarrow R\xrightarrow{\ \times (t-1)\ }R\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @abx oups,  I will edit my question, to avoid commutativity. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: How do you view a free left $R:=\mathbb Z[G]$-module as a $R$-bimodule? Note that the "obvious way" is not well-defined since it depends on how you see a module to be free. For example, let $M$ be the free left $R$-module $R$ of rank 1. For a unit $u\in R$, the right multiplication $u\colon R\to M$ is another way to see $M$ as a free $R$-module, while the "obvious" right multiplications do not coincide (if $u$ is not in the center).

Comment: @Z.M let say that free module in this question is given by a finite direct sum of Z[G]. The multiplication on the right and on the left are the obvious ones.

Comment: It seems to be more natural to look at free bimodule resolutions of Z rather than resolutions by ZG. 1. is equivalent to 2. if you wanted free bimodule resolutions

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg sure, that will be an easy exercise. But I want a finite free resolution of ZG-modules that turns out to be a finite resolution of ZG-bimodules.

Comment: What big class of groups satisfies the two conditions?

Comment: @FernandoMuro there is a big class satisfying condition 1. Essentially my question was about non-abelian groups satisfying 1 and 2.

Comment: @GSM in 2 you don’t want the resolution to be free or projective, do you?

Comment: @FernandoMuro the resulotion I am looking for has to verify 1 and 2 in the same time.

Comment: @GSM this doesn’t quite answer my question.

Comment: @GSM I just realised that my answer doesn’t work. If you unaccept it then I’ll delete it.

Comment: @JeremyRickard but do you still think that there is no such non-abelian group verifying condition 1 and 2?

Comment: @GSM I'm not sure. It's possible that my proof could be fixed, but I haven't managed yet.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I'm sorry you deleted your answer because it looked plausible save for one point I noticed that the centre of the group ring can be a little larger than the group ring of the centre. Does this really cause a lot of difficulty or was there some other problem with your plan?

Comment: @PeterKropholler When I thought that I could identify $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[Z(G)]}\operatorname{coker}(f)$, that gave a contradiction since $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[Z(G)]$-module of rank strictly greater than $1$. But in fact we only have $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])}\operatorname{coker}(f)$, and I couldn't see how to proceed, since $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ may not be a free $Z(\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Let $\Delta$ denote the set of elements of $G$ that have finitely many conjugates: this is a characteristic subgroup and is (locally finite)-by-abelian. Since our group $G$ in the question has finite cohomological dimension over $\mathbb Z$, it follows $\Delta$ is torsion-free abelian of finite rank. So some subgroup $H$ of finite index in $G$ centralises $\Delta$. Now your original line of reasoning works for $H$ so I think you successfully show $G$ must be virtually abelian. That is an interesting reduction.